# 138 Connection Timed out on NoMachine Client - always

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-server, opensuse, nomachine

I am trying to connect from a NoMachine client on a Windows 7 machine to an OpenSUSE machine. I can only connect via NX however I keep running into Error 138:Connection Timed out. I can connect via SSH on my Command prompt however Seem to be unable to connect via here. Does anyone know a solution - been doing this since morning with no light in sight!

Answer (score 0):

Routers supporting UPnP or NAT-PMP are configured automatically to pass connections to NoMachine and all required information is displayed at initial screen (Welcome to NoMachine).

Routers not supporting UPnP or NAT-PMP and Firewalls have to be configured manually to pass traffic to port 4000 (NX protocol), 22 (SSH protocol on Linux/MacOSX) or (4022) (SSH protocol on Windows).

So, check the configuration first.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you point me in the right direction of where to find the config files?

Comment: The configuration of the server can be done by the NoMachine GUI. You should check the server guide on the NoMachine website. It has illustrated documents that show you how to edit the configuration of NoMachine on the remote server. Specifically section 2 about "The Services Panel. Start and Stop a Service or Change its Port"

https://www.nomachine.com/DT11M00107#2

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue setting up my ftp server.
There are a couple of possibilities why the connection was not established, but in my case, and perhaps yours, you must allow the service you're trying to execute in your firewall settings.

In my case I allowed the ftp port and some other specific port for tcp communication.

This (and the proper service, router, etc setup) allowed the communication to be established.